# SQL optimization for large data_sets

Tags: sql, oracle

i got some nasty sql performance issue. I need to execute statment like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(26) */
         a.*, ROWNUM rnum
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM t1
                 WHERE t1_col1 = 'val1'
                   AND g_dom in ('1', '2', '3')
                   AND g_context IN ('3', '4', '5', '6')
                   AND i_col = 1
                   AND f_col in ('1', '2', '3', '4')
                   AND e_g IN (SELECT e_g
                                 FROM t2
                                WHERE t2_col1 = 'val1'
                                  AND g_context IN ('3', '4', '5', '6')
                                  AND val like 'some val%')
                 ORDER BY order_id DESC) a)
 WHERE rnum > 0;
```

Basically we got table `t1` (our data table), and `t2` (our support values). We got 1kk records in `t1` and 10kk in `t2`. Column `g_context` narrows our data sets, but still, val had something like 500k records. We need 25 rows ordered by order_id.

Is there any way to tell inner statement

```
SELECT e_g FROM t2 WHERE t2_col1='val1' AND g_context IN('3','4','5','6' ) AND val like 'some val%
```

to get only 25 records that's match out outer statement criteria ?

Comment: Please show "explain plan" for query. Specify what kind of the conditions in your opinion the most selective. What for condition rnum> 0 ? Is always true

Comment: Is there an index on ORDER_ID?

Comment: What is the `where rnum > 0` predicate doing?  If you only want 25 rows, I assume you would want `rnum <= 25` which should allow the optimizer to use a stopkey in the query plan.  That sounds like what you want but without query plans, it's hard to know.  If there isn't an index that can be scanned to give you the top 25 rows, that's going to be an issue.

Comment: Actually it's production solution - i am not allowed to post real explain plans, data etc. I will try reproduce whole structure, and post here. Right now i can say:
* order_id is indexed
* inner statment is crucial i quess - i dont know how to make it opti-fine in outer statement clause
* rnum > 0 - hmm i need to check api

Answer (score -1):

Why not move rownum and the hint into the inner query like so:

```
SELECT t1.*,row_number() over (order by order_id desc) rn  /*+ FIRST_ROWS(26) */
              FROM t1
             WHERE t1_col1 = 'val1'
               AND g_dom in ('1', '2', '3')
               AND g_context IN ('3', '4', '5', '6')
               AND i_col = 1
               AND f_col in ('1', '2', '3', '4')
               AND e_g IN (SELECT e_g
                             FROM t2
                            WHERE t2_col1 = 'val1'
                              AND g_context IN ('3', '4', '5', '6')
                              AND val like 'some val%')
             ORDER BY order_id DESC
```

Too me this extra subselect with hint and rownum does not seem to make any sense.

And the where-clause should be "WHERE rnum < 26", shouldn't it?